# Girsanov theorem with Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

I am not a student in mathematics, but I am trying to use the following Theorem 8.6.6 (Girsanov theorem II) of Oksendal's SDE with geometric Brownian motion $S_{t}$ instead of the standard Brownian motion $B_{t}$ for my own research. Please help me to do this works. Any references about this question are welcome.

---

According to Theorem 8.6.6 of Oksendal's SDE, with 
$dY(t) = \beta(t, \omega)dt + \theta(t, \omega)dB(t)$; Here $B_{t}$ is a standard Brownian Motion.

Suppose there exist processes $u(t, \omega)$ and $\alpha(t, \omega)$ such that $\theta(t, \omega)u(t, \omega) = \beta(t, \omega) - \alpha(t, \omega)$.

Put $M_{t} = \exp( - \int_{0}^{t}u(s, \omega)dB_{s} - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}u^{2}(s, \omega)ds)$ and $dQ(\omega) = M_{T}dP(\omega)$ on $\mathcal{F}_{T}$.

Assume that $M_{t}$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$ and $P$.

Then $Q$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}_{T}$ and the process $\hat{B}(t) = \int_{0}^{t}u(s, \omega)ds + B(t)$ is a Brownian motion w.r.t. $Q$ and in terms of $\hat{B}(t)$, the process $Y(t)$ has the stochastic integral representation;

$dY(t) = \alpha(t, \omega)dt + \theta(t, \omega)d\hat{B}(t)$.

---

In my case, **I want to find $M_{t}$** which is a martingale, where $B_{t} = S(t)$ is a Geometric Brownian Motion such that $dS_{t} = S_{t}dZ_{t}$ with a standard Brownian Motion $Z_{t}$ and different $\theta(t, \omega)$ and $\hat{\theta}(t, \omega)$ with respect to $dS(t) = S_{t}dZ_{t}$ and $d\hat{S}(t) = \hat{S}_{t}d\hat{Z}_{t}$ respectively. That is,

$dY_{t} = \beta(t, \omega)dt + \theta(t, \omega)dS(t) = \alpha(t, \omega)dt + \hat{\theta}(t, \omega)d\hat{S}(t)$.

I found that the above holds with $\mu(t, \omega) = \theta(t, \omega)^{-1}(\beta(t, \omega) - \alpha(t, \omega))$ and $\hat{S}(t) = \sigma_{t}S(t) - \int_{0}^{t}\mu(s, \omega)ds$ where $\sigma_{t} = \frac{\hat{\theta}(t, \omega)}{\theta(t, \omega)}$. But I am not sure this new $\hat{S}(t)$ is also a Geometric Brownian Motion w.r.t. the new probability measure.

Comment: I realized that Girsanov theorem only can be used for absolutely continuous probability measures and with different level of volatility, this does not hold. Therefore, I can not use the Girsanov theorem.